# Power BI shows only one patch from Matplotlib patch collection

Tags: python, matplotlib, powerbi

I am trying to show a matplotlib plot in Power BI (desktop). It includes Patchcollection. Running the standalone python code gives this:

[image]

But in Power BI, the same code results in this:

[image]

Attaching sample code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.collections
import numpy as np

N = dataset.shape[0]
patches = []

# code to fill in the list patches goes here

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
colors = 100*np.random.random(N)
p = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
p.set_array(colors)
ax.add_collection(p)
plt.autoscale(enable='True', axis='both')

plt.show()
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: Just noticed that the values got doubled for that single patch. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue. I had to choose 'Don't Summarize' in the values tab for each field.